# script to convert a sav file to csv and rename it as original file

Tags: r, shell, csv, spss

I have a script that converts a sav file to csv using R. The challenge is I want the output file name to be same as the filename passed as parameter with .csv extension

syntax is: R-Script.sh  abc.sav

The output file name should be abc.csv

Here is the R code

```
argv <- commandArgs(TRUE)
Datafile <- argv[1]
library(foreign)
dataSPSS <- read.spss(Datafile, to.data.frame=TRUE)
dim(dataSPSS)
write.table(dataSPSS, file = "ifilename.csv", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = "|",eol = "\n", na = "", dec = ".", row.names = FALSE,col.names = TRUE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"))'
```

and the wrapper which is calling the R code:

```
DataFile=$1
Rscript convert_sav-csv.r $DataFile
mv ifilename.csv $DataFile.csv '
```

The output filename is something abc.sav.csv. and I want it to be abc.csv

Comment: Without your script it is difficult to give an absolute answer.  You can extract the name of the file with `strsplit("anyfile.sav", split="[.]")[[1]][1]`

Comment: So you want a `bash` scripting method to make the .csv filename for output? ... `inputFile="$1" ; outputFile=${inputFile%.*}.csv` should handle that part of the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Show us your script! This is easy if your script already parses command line arguments.

Comment: @Thomas please find the code that I am using